# Having troubles with the .map funciton

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, array.prototype.map

I am getting an error on my .map function. I believe the issue is greater than that though because sometimes my fetch comes back as undefined. I have been looking into solutions but haven't found anything that has given me a solution.

Props - is a logged-in user object that has the users ID

discBag consoles as an array sometimes but also will console as undefined. This is where I believe my issue is happening. I have looked into component mounting, but I was confused with the class and super() syntax.

[here is the error I am getting along with the two console.logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xt7wD.png)

I am new to web development and this is my very first stack overflow question. Any solutions or guidance to the solution is greatly appreciated!

```js
function DiscBag(props) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [discBag, setDiscBag] = useState([]);

  const userID = props.user.user.id;
console.log(userID)
console.log(discBag)

  const getDiscs = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`/users/${userID}`)
      const data = await response.json()
      
      setLoading(false)
      setDiscBag(data.discBag)

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }


  };
  useEffect(() => {

    getDiscs();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <div> ....loading bro</div>;
  }
  return (
    <div className="child">
      <p>not loading</p>
      {discBag.map((index, discs) => (
        <div className="discs" key={index}>
          {discs}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: (index,discs) should be (discs,index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, it seems that there are times that the call to your server does not return a `data.discBag` value, which causes the `discBag` state to be empty (and the `map` function can only run on arrays, here is the fix for the problem:

```
{discBag?.map((discs, index) => (
```

Comment: This was helpful but react is still throwing me an error when the call is resolved and data is sent back to the frontend. I am getting. Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {manufacturer, name, _id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: According to the error, this means that the `discBag` is not an `array` but an `object` (and anyway map only works on an array and not an object), please check what `discBag` contains

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I updated my post with a picture of my error alongside the console.log of the array

Comment: @HaimAbeles actually the error implies that `discs` is an object so it would be `{discBag?.map((discs, index) => (<div className="discs" key={discs._id}>{discs.manufacturer}, {discs.name}</div>)}`

Comment: @pilchard Correct

Comment: @jbuck123 Pay attention to the excellent comment written here

Comment: @pilchard amazing comment and solution. Thank you everyone for the help

Comment: @pilchard answer makes more sense since your passing an object! Best of luck mate

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `{discBag.map((discs, index) => ...`  ? first one is element, second one is the index like below;

`array.map((currentElement, index) => { something... })`